# Cannot find identifier 'currentItem' in Kotlin using Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

First of all, I'm new into kotlin and I found issues within my learning process. So I found these errors:

"Cannot find identifier 'Current Item"

The errors occured in the xml file. here is code of the xml file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="args"
            type="com.example.todoapp.fragments.update.UpdateFragment" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="24dp"
        tools:context=".fragments.update.UpdateFragment">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/current_title_et"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"
            android:text="@{args.currentItem.title}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/current_priorities_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:entries="@array/priorities"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:parsePriorityToInt="@{args.currentItem.priority}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_title_et" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/current_description_et"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:hint="@string/description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"
            android:text="@{args.currentItem.description}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_priorities_spinner" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

and this is the kt file

```
package com.example.todoapp.fragments.update

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs
import com.example.todoapp.R
import com.example.todoapp.data.models.ToDoData
import com.example.todoapp.data.viewmodel.ToDoViewModel
import com.example.todoapp.databinding.FragmentUpdateBinding
import com.example.todoapp.fragments.SharedViewModel

class UpdateFragment : Fragment() {

    private val args by navArgs<UpdateFragmentArgs>()

    private val mSharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
    private val mToDoViewModel: ToDoViewModel by viewModels()

    private var _binding: FragmentUpdateBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Data binding
        _binding = FragmentUpdateBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        // Set Menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        // Spinner Item Selected Listener
        binding.currentPrioritiesSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = mSharedViewModel.listener

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.update_fragment_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_save -> updateItem()
            R.id.menu_delete -> confirmItemRemoval()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun updateItem() {
        val title = binding.currentTitleEt.text.toString()
        val description = binding.currentDescriptionEt.text.toString()
        val getPriority = binding.currentPrioritiesSpinner.selectedItem.toString()

        val validation = mSharedViewModel.verifyDataFromUser(title, description)
        if (validation) {
            // Update Current Item
            val updatedItem = ToDoData(
                args.currentItem.id,
                title,
                mSharedViewModel.parsePriority(getPriority),
                description
            )
            mToDoViewModel.updateData(updatedItem)
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Successfully updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // Navigate back
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_updateFragment_to_listFragment)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }

    // Show AlertDialog to Confirm Item Removal
    private fun confirmItemRemoval() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
            mToDoViewModel.deleteItem(args.currentItem)
            Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                "Successfully Removed: ${args.currentItem.title}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_updateFragment_to_listFragment)
        }
        builder.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ -> }
        builder.setTitle("Delete '${args.currentItem.title}'?")
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove '${args.currentItem.title}'?")
        builder.create().show()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

this is the plugin and dependency

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: "kotlin-parcelize"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.todoapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Navigation Component
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Kotlin components
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0-native-mt"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0-native-mt"

}
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help or explanation would be appreciated